# Analysing Signal quality through pogo pins using Hyperlynx

Tags: simulation, signal-integrity, high-speed

I have successfully modeled Linesim and boardsim schematics for quite a few designs in the past and we have been able to do the required SI simulations. I had one question though: On one of our multi-board designs, we connect one board to the other using DE-50 pogo pin by IDI and they do not give any R,L and C values for the pins. They just specify the Length = 1.703", Diameter = 30mils and Resistance of 50 mohms. What is best way to model a pogo pin or any other connector for that matter in Hyperlynx LineSim / BoardSim? Any suggestions? I would think that the best way to do this is to have a lumped circuit equivalent for pogo pin but the manufacturer wouldn't provide any parasitic values.

Thanks for the help.

-Sandeep.

Comment: What frequency range are you interested in?

Comment: We are testing them at 2-3Gbps. It's a SATA interface.